# How to import jars in Altova MapForce

Tags: altova

Hello i am new to Altova Mapforce, I  wanted to know what is the procedure to add JAR files import jars in MapForce.

Regards

RBRK.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean "how do I add jar files that contain user-defined functions for use in my mappings", that is covered in the documentation.

If you mean "how do I add jar files at runtime when running a map", that is what the java classpath is for.

If it's the first one, then read the documentation, make your attempts, and post the results here if it doesn't work.  As posed, your question doesn't really give us enough information about what you are trying to do...Much faster time to resolution, much more likely to get a realistic answer, if you show your work when you describe what you are trying to do.

rip